# Cannot boot to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 64bit version and worked perfect until I removed battery from my notebook and then plugged to the electricity and turned on the notebook. From that time I cannot boot to Ubuntu.

Some errors occur:

```
ELF header smaller than expected
gfxterm not found
/boot/grub/i386-pc/gfxterm_background.mod not found
```

I tried Boot-repair but not work. I do not know what to do next.
When I use **"sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt /dev/sda 
"** then it is installing for i386-pc platform, but I use 64bit.

Comment: Did you remove the battery while the notebook was running? Have you got a URL from Boot-Repair?

Comment: Notebook was off when I remove batery. URL is http://paste.ubuntu.com/23421006